# Displacement map in three.js is causing visible seams on a spherized cube

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping

I am attempting to displace a sphere with 6 generated RGBA `DataTexture`s onto a spherized cube. The displacement leaves a visible seam along the edges of the textures:

[image]

I have tried setting, and tweaking, the following settings:

```
texture.generateMipmaps = true;
texture.wrapS = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
texture.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestMipMapLinearFilter;
```

And have also checked the geometry with a `MeshNormalMaterial` and with the texture as a map on a `MeshBasicMaterial` with no appearance of discontinuities.

I assume there is an issue with computing normals / tangents at the edges, but I've recompute normals after spherizing (with `geom.computeVertexNormals()`) and still see no improvement.

Comment: That "spherized cube", what type of geometry do you use for it?

Comment: I've used either a `BoxGeometry` or `BoxBufferGeometry` (issue occurs with both) and I modify the vertices by doing `vertex.setLength(1)` prior to recalculating normals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the issue was related to the way in which I was standardizing `gl_FragCoord` onto the cube face while generating the textures initially. I was doing:

```
vec2 cubeCoord = (gl_FragCoord.xy * 2.0 / uResolution.xy) - 1.0;
```

Which will generally look fine, except at the edges of the cube faces as it results in the shared edge coordinates being off by 0.5 (in `gl_FragCoord` space). A lot of debugging later, updating to:

```
vec2 cubeCoord = (gl_FragCoord.xy - (uResolution.xy / 2.0)) / ((uResolution.xy / 2.0) - 0.5);
```

And using `texture.minFilter = texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;` worked a charm by guaranteeing that the outer pixels on each cube face's texture are shared exactly by each bordering face.